# Classic Asp and Jquery. Jquery not firing at all

Tags: jquery

I am doing a small classic asp calendar with jQuery. But here jQuery is not firing at all... here I have included small snippet for including jquery script in classic asp. for html and css snippet please refer http://jsfiddle.net/VU6dN/25/

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js">       </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
          alert("i am working");
           }
</script>

<style>
   table#grid tr {
height: 45px;
   }
    table#grid td {
width: 20%;
   }
    table#bottom td {
width: 33%;
    }
    table#grid, table#bottom {
            }
    table#grid, table#bottom {
border: 2px solid #99B7C2;
text-align:center;
width: 300px;
    }
    .activecell {
background-color: #ccc;
    }

   .hidden {
       display: none;   
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing bracket

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
                 alert("i am working");
       }); <<<<
```

Basically ready is a function that takes a function as a parameter, but you failed to close the ready function call.

The more modern syntax for jQuery "ready" is actually just this:

```
      $(function() {
                 alert("i am working");
       });
```

*If you ran this in Chrome with the F12 debug window open, you would have got a read error on the bottom right. Chrome is great for debugging jscript.*